# Creating C++/CLI objects without gcnew

Tags: c++, c++-cli, clr

Is it advisable to create local C++/CLI objects without `gcnew`? 
Which of the following creations of `string` objects `str1` and `str2` is correct or preferred?

```
void foo()
{
    System::String str1("string 1");
    System::String^ str2 = gcnew System::String("string 2");

   // Do something with the strings 
}
```

Comment: Neither is correct, System::String is highly optimized and has a dedicated CIL opcode.  Using stack semantics on a class that does not implement IDisposable is least correct, it doesn't otherwise avoid gcnew since the compiler auto-generates it.  Should be `String^ str1 = "string1".`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creating a reference-type object (`ref class`) without `gcnew` is called [stack semantics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177191.aspx).

It's meant to *mirror* the plain C++ feature of creating an object on the stack. It also enables RAII: if your object implememnts `IDisposable` (or in C++/CLI terms if it has a destructor), its `Dispose` (destructor) method will be called when you leave the scope where it's declared (either normally or through exception propagation). Just like a plain C++ destructor would be called.

Under the hood, the object is created on the managed heap *in either case* even under stack semantics.

So, there's an obvious benefit of using stack semantics for RAII. If your object is not disposable, you *may* end up with less cluttered code (you use less `^` characters and use `.` instead of `->`) but it may confuse the reader. It's your call.

Comment: 'Benefit of stack semantics for RAII' is  an interesting point. Thanks.

Comment: It's worth noting that there is a disadvantage to using stack semantics: It becomes harder to pass the object as a parameter to other .Net methods, since the .Net library declares methods with the `^` on the parameters.